# Ubuntu not recognizing full ram

Tags: ram

I have 32 GB of RAM install in my Dell Optiplex 990.

```
lab@lab-445:~/Desktop/M_series_assembly/M4-M5$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32058      28989       3068          0       8424      18706
-/+ buffers/cache:       1859      30198
Swap:        30516          0      30516
```

How can it be even when I am not running anything?

---

Here is the requested list of installed 32bit applications:

```
lab@lab-445:~$ dpkg -l | grep i386  

ii  gcc-4.6-base:i386                               4.6.3-1ubuntu5                                      GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386                          1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - ASN.1 library
ii  libasound2:i386                                 1.0.25-1ubuntu10.2                                  shared library for ALSA applications
ii  libavahi-client3:i386                           0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1                                   Avahi client library
ii  libavahi-common-data:i386                       0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1                                   Avahi common data files
ii  libavahi-common3:i386                           0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1                                   Avahi common library
ii  libc6:i386                                      2.15-0ubuntu10.7                                    Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-i386                                      2.15-0ubuntu10.7                                    Embedded GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libcapi20-3:i386                                1:3.12.20071127-0ubuntu11                           libraries for CAPI support
ii  libcomerr2:i386                                 1.42-1ubuntu2                                       common error description library
ii  libcroco3:i386                                  0.6.5-1ubuntu0.1                                    Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) parsing and manipulation toolkit
ii  libcups2:i386                                   1.5.3-0ubuntu8.5                                    Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Core library
ii  libdb5.1:i386                                   5.1.25-11build1                                     Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdbus-1-3:i386                                1.4.18-1ubuntu1.7                                   simple interprocess messaging system (library)
ii  libdrm-intel1:i386                              2.4.52-1~precise1                                   Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-nouveau1a:i386                           2.4.52-1~precise1                                   Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm-radeon1:i386                             2.4.52-1~precise1                                   Userspace interface to radeon-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libdrm2:i386                                    2.4.52-1~precise1                                   Userspace interface to kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  libexif12:i386                                  0.6.20-2ubuntu0.1                                   library to parse EXIF files
ii  libexpat1:i386                                  2.0.1-7.2ubuntu1.1                                  XML parsing C library - runtime library
ii  libffi6:i386                                    3.0.11~rc1-5                                        Foreign Function Interface library runtime
ii  libfontconfig1:i386                             2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1                                    generic font configuration library - runtime
ii  libfreetype6:i386                               2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1                                    FreeType 2 font engine, shared library files
ii  libgcc1:i386                                    1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5                                    GCC support library
ii  libgcrypt11:i386                                1.5.0-3ubuntu0.3                                    LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
ii  libgd2-xpm:i386                                 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6ubuntu2                            GD Graphics Library version 2
ii  libgettextpo0:i386                              0.18.1.1-5ubuntu3                                   GNU Internationalization library
ii  libgif4:i386                                    4.1.6-9ubuntu1                                      library for GIF images (library)
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                            8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7                                    free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                            8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7                                    free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:i386                              8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7                                    free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglib2.0-0:i386                               2.32.4-0ubuntu1                                     GLib library of C routines
ii  libglu1-mesa:i386                               8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7                                    Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libgnutls26:i386                                2.12.14-5ubuntu3.8                                  GNU TLS library - runtime library
ii  libgomp1:i386                                   4.6.3-1ubuntu5                                      GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
ii  libgpg-error0:i386                              1.10-2ubuntu1                                       library for common error values and messages in GnuPG components
ii  libgphoto2-2:i386                               2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2                                   gphoto2 digital camera library
ii  libgphoto2-port0:i386                           2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2                                   gphoto2 digital camera port library
ii  libgpm2:i386                                    1.20.4-4                                            General Purpose Mouse - shared library
ii  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386                           1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.5                          MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - krb5 GSS-API Mechanism
ii  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386                         1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - GSSAPI support library
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386            0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1                                  GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer0.10-0:i386                         0.10.36-1ubuntu1                                    Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386                        1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - crypto library
ii  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386                       1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - Base library
ii  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386                       1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - NTLM support library
ii  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386                         1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - X509 support library
ii  libice6:i386                                    2:1.0.7-2build1                                     X11 Inter-Client Exchange library
ii  libieee1284-3:i386                              0.2.11-10build1                                     cross-platform library for parallel port access
ii  libjpeg-turbo8:i386                             1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.4                            IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg8:i386                                   8c-2ubuntu7                                         Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libk5crypto3:i386                               1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.5                          MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Crypto Library
ii  libkeyutils1:i386                               1.5.2-2                                             Linux Key Management Utilities (library)
ii  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386                         1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - libraries
ii  libkrb5-3:i386                                  1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.5                          MIT Kerberos runtime libraries
ii  libkrb5support0:i386                            1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.5                          MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Support library
ii  liblcms1:i386                                   1.19.dfsg-1ubuntu3                                  Little CMS color management library
ii  libldap-2.4-2:i386                              2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.4                                 OpenLDAP libraries
ii  libllvm3.0:i386                                 3.0-4ubuntu1                                        Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
ii  libltdl7:i386                                   2.4.2-1ubuntu1                                      A system independent dlopen wrapper for GNU libtool
ii  libmpg123-0:i386                                1.12.1-3.2ubuntu1                                   MPEG layer 1/2/3 audio decoder -- runtime library
ii  libncurses5:i386                                5.9-4                                               shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libopenal1:i386                                 1:1.13-4ubuntu3                                     Software implementation of the OpenAL API (shared library)
ii  liborc-0.4-0:i386                               1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2                                   Library of Optimized Inner Loops Runtime Compiler
ii  libp11-kit0:i386                                0.12-2ubuntu1                                       Library for loading and coordinating access to PKCS#11 modules - runtime
ii  libpciaccess0:i386                              0.12.902-1ubuntu0.2                                 Generic PCI access library for X
ii  libpcre3:i386                                   8.12-4                                              Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - runtime files
ii  libpng12-0:i386                                 1.2.46-3ubuntu4                                     PNG library - runtime
ii  libroken18-heimdal:i386                         1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - roken support library
ii  libsane:i386                                    1.0.22-7ubuntu1                                     API library for scanners
ii  libsasl2-2:i386                                 2.1.25.dfsg1-3ubuntu0.1                             Cyrus SASL - authentication abstraction library
ii  libsasl2-modules:i386                           2.1.25.dfsg1-3ubuntu0.1                             Cyrus SASL - pluggable authentication modules
ii  libselinux1:i386                                2.1.0-4.1ubuntu1                                    SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libsm6:i386                                     2:1.2.0-2build1                                     X11 Session Management library
ii  libsqlite3-0:i386                               3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1                                    SQLite 3 shared library
ii  libssl1.0.0:i386                                1.0.1-4ubuntu5.20                                   SSL shared libraries
ii  libstdc++6:i386                                 4.6.3-1ubuntu5                                      GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libtasn1-3:i386                                 2.10-1ubuntu1.2                                     Manage ASN.1 structures (runtime)
ii  libtiff4:i386                                   3.9.5-2ubuntu1.6                                    Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library
ii  libtinfo5:i386                                  5.9-4                                               shared low-level terminfo library for terminal handling
ii  libunistring0:i386                              0.9.3-5                                             Unicode string library for C
ii  libusb-0.1-4:i386                               2:0.1.12-20                                         userspace USB programming library
ii  libuuid1:i386                                   2.20.1-1ubuntu3.1                                   Universally Unique ID library
ii  libv4l-0:i386                                   0.8.6-1ubuntu2                                      Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:i386                             0.8.6-1ubuntu2                                      Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  libwind0-heimdal:i386                           1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1                   Heimdal Kerberos - stringprep implementation
ii  libx11-6:i386                                   2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2                               X11 client-side library
ii  libx11-xcb1:i386                                2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2                               Xlib/XCB interface library
ii  libxau6:i386                                    1:1.0.6-4                                           X11 authorisation library
ii  libxcb-glx0:i386                                1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                                    X C Binding, glx extension
ii  libxcb1:i386                                    1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                                    X C Binding
ii  libxcomposite1:i386                             1:0.4.3-2build1                                     X11 Composite extension library
ii  libxcursor1:i386                                1:1.1.12-1ubuntu0.1                                 X cursor management library
ii  libxdamage1:i386                                1:1.1.3-2build1                                     X11 damaged region extension library
ii  libxdmcp6:i386                                  1:1.1.0-4                                           X11 Display Manager Control Protocol library
ii  libxext6:i386                                   2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1                                  X11 miscellaneous extension library
ii  libxfixes3:i386                                 1:5.0-4ubuntu4.2                                    X11 miscellaneous 'fixes' extension library
ii  libxi6:i386                                     2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1~precise1                       X11 Input extension library
ii  libxinerama1:i386                               2:1.1.1-3ubuntu0.1                                  X11 Xinerama extension library
ii  libxml2:i386                                    2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.11                            GNOME XML library
ii  libxpm4:i386                                    1:3.5.9-4                                           X11 pixmap library
ii  libxrandr2:i386                                 2:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.2                                  X11 RandR extension library
ii  libxrender1:i386                                1:0.9.6-2ubuntu0.1                                  X Rendering Extension client library
ii  libxslt1.1:i386                                 1.1.26-8ubuntu1.3                                   XSLT 1.0 processing library - runtime library
ii  libxt6:i386                                     1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1                                  X11 toolkit intrinsics library
ii  libxxf86vm1:i386                                1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1                                  X11 XFree86 video mode extension library
ii  syslinux-legacy                                 2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu5                                Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  wine-gecko1.4:i386                              1.4.0-0ubuntu2                                      Microsoft Windows compatibility layer (embedded web browser)
ii  wine1.4-i386:i386                               1.4-0ubuntu4.1                                      Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (32-bit support)
ii  zlib1g:i386                                     1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4                             compression library - runtime
```

and the machine information:

```
lab@lab-445:~$ uname -a
Linux lab-445 3.2.0-65-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:03:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The `check-my-memory.py` file you tried to download is not existing any more. That's not your fault, the website owner removed it. I therefore decided to edit your question and remove this paragraph. If you disagree, feel free to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RAM is fully recognized, as it says `32058`MB total.

I guess you think instead that your memory is fully used although nothing is running? This is not true, because you have `30198`MB of memory available for your applications.

The rest that does not show up as "free memory" (`3068`MB) is used as cache. This is a great technology that makes HDD access much faster by caching data that Ubuntu thinks you might need soon from the disk into the free RAM. This cache is not shown as "free", but is available because the kernel can drop cache immediately when RAM is needed for your applications.

See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for more well visualized and easily  understandable information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...in another machine (8 cpu) i have same memory (32 GB).one application which is running fine in the later,while i cant run it in the first machine and its showing "Run out of memory"  although before the crash it has used only 5 GB of the memory and rest 26 was free.

Comment: Is any program/system/CPU related to this 32bit?

Comment: Sorry i dont get you properly...are you asking wat program is creating the problem or something else? If first one, then i am trying to run a assembler (454)..recently i have upgrade the ram and i checked even from bios that all the four ran is recognized and accessible..anything other than that you wanted to know?

Comment: No, I wanted to know whether any component involved in this problem (your CPU, your operating system, any running software) uses the old 32bit architecture instead of the new 64bit. Because 32bit only allow a program to address around 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Pardon me but i still dont understand your question..both the machine is 64 bit (Dell optiplex 990 and dell precision T1700)..for switching to ECC ram i bought T1700 later..i really have no idea wat is involved in the problem..some one suggest me that as i upgrade the memory of Optiplex from 8 to 32 GB,it may creat some problem and now i have to reinstall ubuntu again..

Comment: Do you have any 32bit programs installed? You have if the terminal command `dpkg -l | grep i386` has any output. And you could also post the output of `uname -a`, please.

Comment: @chayan: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: You are running a multiarch system. That means you have applications (or at least libraries) of multiple architectures (32bit or 64bit) installed. The problem with 32bit applications is that they may only allocate up to 4GB RAM per instance. So if your problematic application uses a 32bit library and that one tries to allocate much memory, it probably crashes as soon as it tries to pass that 4GB boundary. You could compare the `dpkg -l | grep i386` output of your problematic machine with the one of the computer where the program works. Are there any differences?